# How to make my popup page as Child page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

How to make my popup page as Child page.

Description:

```
User can not do any operation in parent page till the popup page is not closed.
It should only allow after popup page is closed.
```

Comment: You have not posted any code, or even a meaningful question. You appear to have posted something from a uni assignment. Please read the rules before posting questions.

Comment: Is that description by any chance, a line copied from some requirement document?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax modal popup extender..

At first you must have a Scriptmanager as

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Declare a button to be functioned as TargetControlID of modal popup...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" CssClass="m-btn purple" style="display:none" />
```

After that a modal popup extender as

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopup1" runat="server" DynamicServicePath="" 
 Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" CancelControlID="idclose" Drag="true" popupControlID="Name of your popup" >
 </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

In code behind you can call your popup as..

```
ModalPopup1.show();
```

Refer [Here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-show-modalpopup-to-edit-gridview.html) for more details...